# Alteranative way without switch/If else - C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, coding-style

I'm having the below C# code and it is the general scenario in the code to write if/else or switch based on the functionality.

In same function am writing multiple lines which increase the code complexity numbers.

Is there any alternate better way I can implement without else if? Any other suggestion are welcome.

```
//Sample Piece of code to highlight my scenario. may have syntax errors
IEnumerable<lst> fnc(string category)
{
    using(Context sample = new Context())
    {
        if (category == "A")
        {
            return from T1  in  sample.TableName 
                   join T2 in sample.A on T1.id = T2.id
                   where cat= category
                   select T1
        }
        else if (category == "B")
        {
            return from T1  in  sample.TableName 
                   join T2 in sample.B on T1.Eid = T2.id
                   where cat= category
                   select T1
        }
        else if (category == "C")
        {
            return from T1  in  sample.TableName 
                   join T2 in sample.C on T1.id = T2.id
                   where cat= category
                   select T1
        }
        // ...
        else if (category == "I")
        {
            return from T1  in  sample.TableName 
                   join T2 in sample.I on T1.id = T2.id
                   where cat= category
                   select T1
         }
         else
         { /* return ... */ }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Showing condition would make it more clear

Comment: what is `cond I`,`cond A` etc?

Comment: Do you have this switch on category in one place, or it is repeated over application?

Comment: @Adil Am editing my question to add some code. But basicaslly it will be hitting DB with different "where" condtion

Comment: @Peru can you provide sample this where conditions?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy  it is in one placer which am trying to avoid with better ways. And it may come in multiple places  as we move on !

Comment: @Peru please, show at least two linq queries for us to understand what happening

Comment: @Adil Updated with Linq code

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Updated my code snippet

Comment: ahh you don't change the condition. You change the join.

Comment: what is `sam`? if it your class you can add indexer to it

Comment: @Peru what is `i` in your queries and what is `sam`?

Comment: Yes i change the join as well. misspelled it is sample

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy i updated code again. Hope am clear this time.

Comment: you can use `Dynamic LINQ` from answer @Balachandra

Answer (score 3):

You could build an dictionary to store the conditions:

```
var array = new[] {10, 20, 30};
var conditions = new Dictionary<string, Func<int, bool>>
{
    {"A", input => input > 10},
    {"B", input => input > 20}
};

if (conditions.ContainsKey(category))
{
    return array.Where(conditions[category]);
}
else
{
    // else :>
}
```

int must be replaced with your type you store in the enumerable.

Comment: for linq-to-sql this is possibly work not in all cases

Answer (score 2):

```
IEnumerable<lst> fnc(string category)
{
    return JoinByCategory(sample.TableName, category)
             .Where(t1 => t1.cat == category);
}

private IQueryable<T1> JoinByCategory(IQueryable<T1> outer, string category)
{
   switch(category)
   {
      case "A": return outer.Join(sample.A, t1=> t1.id, a=> a.id, (t1,a)=> t1);
      case "B": return outer.Join(sample.B, t1=> t1.Eid, b=> b.id, (t1,b)=> t1);
      ...
      default:
         throw new ArgumentException();
   }
}
```

Comment: so, you move switch from `fnc` to another function :-)

Comment: @Grundy well, I moved part which varies (join) out from code which stays same. And yes, I prefer `switch` to dictionary when we deal with small fixed set of cases. Nice alternative to switch will be polymorphism, but I don't think it worth introducing class hierarchy in this case :)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Thanks for the answer. Guess i need more time to understand this concepts :) .Any suggestion or article where i can start these basics with ?

Comment: @Peru msdn :-) all about `IQueryable`

Comment: @Grundy Thanks. Closer look at this had answers wit IQueryable for Delayed Execution :). Think i  need to improve writing my Lamda Exp

Comment: @Peru, as Grundy stated, it's all about `IQueryable`. You have queries written in Query Syntax, which is translated into Method Syntax by compiler. Method Syntax is very handy when you have to compose your queries based on some conditions. Take a look on [Queries in LINQ to Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399367.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can create `Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Entity, bool>>>` (or `Dictionary<string, Func<CollectionItem, bool>>` for LINQ to Objects) and use it instead of `if`/`else` or `switch`/`case`:

```
private Conditions = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<YourLinqEntityClass, bool>>>() {
    { "A", /* cond A */ },
    { "B", /* cond B */ },
    { "C", /* cond C */ },
    // (...)
    { "I", /* cond I */ }
}

IEnumerable<lst> fnc()
{
    if(Conditions.ContainsKey(category))
        return db.Entities.Where(Conditions(category));
    return db.Entities;
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code and my join changes based on condition. Is it possible with above method ? Can you share some code if yes

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). Create an array of all the conditions. Then based on 'Category' condition get the array index and use it in LINQ Expression.

Answer (score 1):

as you mentioned you have different joins for different conditions, but still, you could put all your queries into a dictionary with a string key, something like:

```
    private static Dictionary<string, Func<DataContext, IEnumerable<lst>>> functions = new Dictionary<string, Func<DataContext, IEnumerable<lst>>>() 
    { 
        {"A", 
         delegate(DataContext dbCtx)
         {
            return new List<lst>(); // your query here...
         }
        },
        {"B", 
         delegate(DataContext dbCtx)
         {
            return new List<lst>();
         }
        },
        {"C", 
         delegate(DataContext dbCtx)
         {
            return new List<lst>();
         }
        }
    };

    public IEnumerable<string> fnc(string category)
    {
        if (!(functions.ContainsKey(category)))
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        using(Context sample = new Context()
        {
            return functions[category].Invoke(sample);
        }
    }
```

hope it helps...

Comment: i think you mean `functions[category]`

Comment: indeed... sorry, i am using vb.net for quite a while and almost forgot c# syntax, shame on that

Answer (score 0):

The switch command can be replaced with a Map extension method:

```
return externalCode
    .Map("A", from T1 in sample.TableName
            join T2 in sample.A on T1.id = T2.id 
            where cat = category
            select T1)
    .Map("B", from T1 in sample.TableName
            join T2 in sample.B on T1.Eid = T2.id 
            where cat = category
            select T1)
    .Map("C", from T1 in sample.TableName
            join T2 in sample.C on T1.id = T2.id 
            where cat = category
            select T1)
    .Map("I", from T1 in sample.TableName
            join T2 in sample.I on T1.id = T2.id 
            where cat = category
            select T1)
    .Else(...)
```

More examples and source: [here](http://www.siepman.nl/blog/post/2013/07/21/mapping-map-switch.aspx).